# Is it possible to highlight features within a user drawn polygon using the Mapbox API?

Tags: javascript, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

Mapbox provides an example using a bounding box with a queryRenderedFeatures call.

Highlight features within a bounding box
https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/using-box-queryrenderedfeatures/

I would like to do this with a polygon instead of a bounding box.
I know how to draw the polygon. I don't know how to query the rendered features with a polygon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most straightforward way would be to use Turf's [pointsWithinPolygon](http://turfjs.org/docs/#pointsWithinPolygon) function, assuming they are points. Depending on your exact needs, [booleanWithin](http://turfjs.org/docs/#booleanWithin) or [booleanOverlap](http://turfjs.org/docs/#booleanOverlap) might be what you want instead.

Comment: The Turf method booleanIntersects worked.